# Why is my socket doing nothing?

Tags: java, sockets

I have a class called JSocket that I'm making for my friend (because he's bad with sockets so I'm trying to make it easier for him). When I call the `connect()` method it finishes fairly quick, but after calling the `getOutput()` method, it failed. Here's my socket class:

```
public class JSocket {

    public static String conn, tempLine;
    public static int port;
    public static boolean isURL = false;
    public Socket socket;
    BufferedReader in;
    PrintWriter out;

    public JSocket(String conn, int port) {
        this.conn = conn;
        this.port = port;
        try {
            socket = new Socket(conn, port);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public JSocket connect() {
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())));
            out.write("GET / HTTP/1.0");
            out.flush();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return this;
    }

    public String getOutput() {
        String line;
        String output = "";
        try {
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                output += line;
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            line = "err";
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

And my main:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JSocket js = new JSocket("google.com", 80);
        js.connect();
        System.out.println("Connected");
        System.out.println("Conn: " + js.getOutput());
        return;
    }
}
```

It prints "Connected," then a while later it prints "Conn: " with nothing else. I'm trying to get the source of the google webpage, I don't want to be stupid and I feel like I made some stupid answer. Can anyone help? (Also, I added the tag "raw-sockets," I think this is a raw socket, please correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: This isn't a raw socket. It's a regular socket.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HTTP `GET` line must be terminated by a newline,
and then you need a blank line to mark the end of the request header.
Until then, the server keeps waiting for you to complete the request.

Change this line:

```
out.write("GET / HTTP/1.0");
```

To this:

```
out.write("GET / HTTP/1.0\n\n");
```

Comment: Welp, I was right in one way... it was a stupid mistake. Thanks!